# How to set size of scrollview as the size of textview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using Textview which has dynamic any length data. i want to set the size of scrollview to more than the size of Textview.

How can i set the size of scrollview as the size of Textview ?

Thanks in Advance ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've found the following Code on the Internet and it works very well:

```
- (float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{

    [text retain];
    [withFont retain];
    CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 1000.0) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

    [text release];
    [withFont release];
    NSLog(@"%f", suggestedSize.height);
    return suggestedSize.height;

}
```

I use this in my own app like this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, [self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:thetext :[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0] :320 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap]);
```